# Steam OpenId realm and returnUrl

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, openid, steam

I'm working on an application which use [node-steam-openid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-steam-openid).

I import it like this `const SteamAuth = require("node-steam-openid");`

When i create the `SteamAuth` object, 3 params are require *realm*, *returnUrl* and *apiKey*:

```
const steam = new SteamAuth({
    realm: "https://example.net", // Site name displayed to users on logon
    returnUrl: "https://rest_site.net/test/api/auth/steam/authenticate", // Your return route
    apiKey: apiKey // Steam API key 
});
```

**In this case *returnUrl* is an API call that triggers my function in the backend that actually retrieves the user data and save the steamId in database.**

**The issue** is that once opened the steam auth and insert the credentials, it gives me a  [generic error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hept.png)

---

The first thing that came to my mind is that *returnUrl* must not be an API call, so i change the `SteamAuth` object params:

```
const steam = new SteamAuth({
    realm: "https://example.net", // Site name displayed to users on logon
    returnUrl: "https://example.net/test_auth", // Your return route
    apiKey: apiKey // Steam API key
 });
```

With this new params, after steam authentication success, i'm being redirect (correctly) to `https://example.net/test_auth`

I wonder why I can't insert an API call as return route after steam authentication success

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem there was that your returnURL wasn't in the same realm that you specified.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).